# FloatingActionButton with animated icon

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button

I am trying to create a FloatingActionButton with an icon like this : https://github.com/jd-alexander/LikeButton

As you can see, the button is **animated**, it is not just two different buttons who are changed.

Here is my actual basic FloatingActionButton, with a static icon :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_white_24dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

I do not want to just change the icon, I would like to make an animation when I click on it.

Here is the button I need, but in this case it is not included in the FloatingActionButton :

```
<com.like.LikeButton
    android:id="@+id/like_button"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    app:icon_type="heart"
    app:circle_start_color="@color/red"
    app:like_drawable="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
    app:unlike_drawable="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_white_24dp"
    app:dots_primary_color="@color/orange"
    app:dots_secondary_color="@color/red"
    app:circle_end_color="@color/orange"
    app:icon_size="24dp"
    app:anim_scale_factor="1"/>
```

To sum up :

1. I know how to do a FloatingActionButton with a static icon.
2. I know how to create an animated like button
3. I do not know how to mix steps 1) and 2) to create a FloatingActionButton with an animated icon on click.

A famous shopping app is doing it, but I do not know how.

[image]

Comment: do you got what you need ??

Answer (score 2):

I think that the way to achieve that is not by using a `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`, but instead create your own FAB that extends a container like a `FrameLayout` (or maybe even a `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`), set a rounded drawable background to it, and add the `com.like.LikeButton` as a child. Probably you will have to define a `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` as well for it if you want to use it in a `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`. Just use `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` as a source of inspiration if needed :P

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a great idea! Havan't done it myself, but this is how I would do it:

1) FAB's are child from [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html)

2) ImageView's can be [Animated.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html)

3) Have Fun!

Comment: My like icon isn't a Animated ImageView :(